# Finding Limit $\lim_{x \to \infty} (2^x + 3^x + 5^x + 7 ^x + 11 ^x +13^x)^{\frac{1}{x}}$

Tags: limits

Finding Limit

$$\lim_{x \to \infty} (2^x + 3^x + 5^x + 7 ^x + 11 ^x +13^x)^{\frac{1}{x}}$$

So I let

$$y = (2^x + 3^x + 5^x + 7 ^x + 11 ^x +13^x)^{\frac{1}{x}}$$

$\ln$ both sides:

$$\ln{y} = \frac{1}{x} \ln {(2^x + 3^x + 5^x + 7 ^x + 11 ^x +13^x)}$$

Now what?

Comment: Have you tried plugging in values of $x$?

Comment: Well, your $\ln y$ has indeterminate form $\infty/\infty$

Comment: Maybe use the idea [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/111661/is-3x-lt-1-2x-3x-lt-3-cdot-3x-right)?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

From the idea in the question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/111661/is-3x-lt-1-2x-3x-lt-3-cdot-3x-right), for $x>0$:
$$
13^x<2^x+3^x+5^x+7^x+11^x+13^x <6\cdot 13^x;
$$
whence
$$
13 <(2^x+3^x+5^x+7^x+11^x+13^x )^{1/x}<6^{1/x}\cdot13.
$$
Now use the squeeze theorem.

Comment: In general, if $a_i \gt 0$, then


$$\lim_{x \to \infty} (a_1^x + a_2^x + \dots + a_n^x)^{\frac{1}{x}} = \max a_i$$. There is also a similar formula for $\min a_i$ (taking $x \to -\infty$).

Comment: @Aryabhata That shouldn't be hard to prove. Putting $${a_n}^x < \sum\limits_{k = 1}^n {{a_n}^x}  < n{a_n}^x$$ should do the trick.

Comment: @PeterT.off: Right, that works.